# Carbon app does not receive kEventWindowDrawContent on unhiding

Tags: macos-carbon

I noticed that my old Carbon application does not receive kEventWindowDrawContent when unhiding the application. I can easily solve this problem by just redrawing everything once I get the kEventWindowExpanded event but I'm still confused as to why my app doesn't get the kEventWindowDrawContent event when the app is brought back from hidden state.

I checked all the old Apple docs and there's no explicit mentioning that kEventWindowDrawContent will be sent when an app is unhidden, but common sense implies that it should be sent because the app needs to be redrawn.

I do get the initial kEventWindowDrawContent message when opening my window, though, so the event handler must have been installed correctly.

Does anybody remember anything about this old Carbon stuff? Is kEventWindowDrawContent supposed to be sent on unhiding or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer I received from an Apple engineer:

> kEventWindowDrawContent is sent when the window content has been
>   invalidated. We don’t invalidate window content by default when a
>   window is expanded from minimized state; the window buffer is kept
>   valid while the window is minimized (so that any drawing into the
>   window will be reflected in the window’s Dock tile), so it’s assumed
>   that unless the app explicitly invalidates, there is not any reason to
>   redraw the window just because it’s been expanded.

In other words: Applications can still draw to a window even while it is minimized. It will be buffered and automatically drawn when the window is expanded again. So no kEventWindowDrawContent is sent in this case because the window buffer hasn't been invalidated.